# How to get MultiFactor in firebase sdk?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to enable/add multi-factor authentication in my firebase app.
I"ve gotten the latest firebase SDK (ver 9.1.4) and I've upgraded my firebase Authentication to include MultiFactor per the instructions.

I'm following these instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/multi-factor#web-version-8_4

In my code, I get reference to the current user and I've confirmed the user object exists.
Then I try this:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
user.multiFactor.getSession().then(function(multiFactorSession) {
       console.log('test')
      })
```

But when I run this I get:

**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSession')**
The user object doesn't seem to have the multiFactor component.

What am I missing?

here is my firebase file where I import references

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import "firebase/storage";
import 'firebase/messaging';
```

After further efforts, I realized it the latest sDK was not loading correclty and that it needed Node 14+ to work. Once I updated Node version, the ver 9 of sdk loaded and everything worked correctly.